# why is a piecewise function f(x) left differentiable at c if and only if f(left)=f(c)?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, piecewise-continuity

why is a piecewise function f(x) left differentiable at c if and only if f(left)=f(c)?
[rule for differentiability](http://calculus.subwiki.org/w/index.php?title=Differentiation_rule_for_piecewise_definition_by_interval&oldid=3120#Everywhere_version)

Answer (score 1):

It's not. You may have missed seeing the hypothesis (just above this claim on the linked page) that $f_1$ and $f_2$ are differentiable everywhere.

For instance, the function $f(x) = \begin{cases}x & \text{$x$ rational and negative} \\0 & \text{$x$ irrational and negative} \\ 0 & \text{$x$ positive} \end{cases}$

has a left limit that equals $f(0)$, but is certainly not left-differentiable.

Comment: so for a problem like $f(x)=\left{(2x-2,x<3@2x-4,x≥3\right)$

Comment: Sorry, struggle-bus here, would the function not be left-differentiable here?

Comment: f(x) =
\begin{cases}
2x-2,  & \text{if $x<3$} \\
2x-4, & \text{if $x≥$}
\end{cases}

Comment: In the example in the comment that formatted correctly (except for the missing 3), the left function is indeed differentiable, with derivative 2. But the left and right values at the join-point, 4 and 2, are different. And if you try to compute $f(x) - f(3)$ for values of $x < 3$, you end up taking $f(x) - 2$ rather than $f(x) - 4$, as would be needed to make the derivative work out right.